# Можно ли опустить border?

Tags: html, css

Надо чтобы цифра стояла прямо напротив бордера блока, возможно ли как то опустить на пару пикселей подчеркивания или надо делать отдельный блок в род блоке и задавать ему бордер?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Такой вариант устроит?

```css
body {
  color: #666;
}

.border-bottom {
  display: block;
  text-align: right;
  border-bottom: 2px dotted #333;
  color: #333;
  padding: 2px 0;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer non quam eget justo eleifend dictum vel imperdiet purus. Ut et iaculis nulla. Suspendisse sit amet porttitor odio. Vivamus velit turpis, varius pulvinar ultricies sit amet, blandit ut tortor. Integer vitae efficitur augue. Sed egestas ligula sit amet sapien varius, vel hendrerit augue cursus. Suspendisse eget dui eu neque tincidunt dapibus. Praesent eget sapien felis. Integer interdum diam vel sodales euismod. Proin id feugiat massa. Quisque cursus, lectus sit amet hendrerit tincidunt, ligula eros sollicitudin nulla, non tristique nulla nulla sit amet nulla.
<div class="border-bottom">4</div>
Donec vehicula malesuada ante sit amet sollicitudin. Vivamus nec metus neque. Donec vitae arcu sed turpis iaculis luctus ut sed arcu. In consectetur pretium lacus, et ornare dolor mollis ut. Nullam tincidunt ut leo sed facilisis. Pellentesque accumsan pretium ante, et porta diam tempor sit amet. Integer quam ligula, mattis nec aliquam rutrum, pulvinar eget felis. Cras condimentum, augue quis scelerisque semper, est risus pharetra risus, ut semper lectus orci vitae ipsum.
```